# ajax is not getting executed

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Hi i have ajax in my project, in other files, but for this one particular instance where I call scripts/claim.php and pass in an id parameter via GET it doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="claimid" value =<?php echo $fetch_donate['id'];?>>
<input type="button" onclick="processclaim();" class="btn" value="claim - <?php   if($donate_type=='generic'){ echo $ebase;} else { echo $fetch_donate['ebase'];}?> PP"></div>
```

PHP

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['id'])) {
   ....
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>

function processclaim() {

    alert("hi");
    var id=document.getElementById('claimid').value;
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "scripts/claim.php", 
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = "profile.php";    
        }

    });

    alert(id);

}

</script>
```

the alerts work, displays "hi" and the correct id that is passed.

Comment: Have you used browser developer tools to find what response your AJAX call is getting?

Comment: `&& isset($_POST['id'])) {` via GET.?

Comment: What's `$_POST['id']` value ?

Comment: Is your `if` statemeng being executed ?

Comment: nope, how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error back from your server, add that state to the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "scripts/claim.php", 
    data: {id: id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        window.location = "profile.php";    
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error("ERROR!", arguments);
    }
});
```

My guess is you are setting the dataType coming back as JSON and it is not being returned from the server as JSON.